# PHP 5.3: fgetcsv and missing letters

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

When I read from a csv file with `fgetcsv` method it removes "Å" and "Ø" if they are at the beginning of the string.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        echo $data[0]."<br />";
}
```

assume my csv contains only one row `ÅbyÅÅÅÅhøjÅ`, the output is `byÅÅÅÅhøjÅ` (note lack of the "Å" at the beginning)

any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps watching about the "Encoding" of your file and your PHP script : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php : "Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just wrapped input in quotes - now always first character for strings will be ".

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of `fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> **NOTE**
>
> Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG
>   is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this
>   function.

This means you will need to match the encoding of your string to your locale setting (or vice versa). There is also a [bug report on bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55507) concerning the inconsistent handling of unexpected characters in the input string.

Comment: Just a side note: We have run into so many issues with PHP's csv handling that we wrote our own csv parser.

Comment: Haha, exactly what I say in my comment.